# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS has a length or size limit?

Tags: php, curl

I want to send with an API some POST data with a large information data from server `a` to server `b`.
Into server `b`, I receive only a part of posts data even if with `htaccess` I increased POST size and other.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 400M
php_value post_max_size 400M
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 400
php_value memory_limit 400M
```

There is a limit of posts data sent with a cURL? or.. anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Sending data via POST does not have a limit except for the one you have set in your server (php_value post_max_size 400M);

you might want to check your timeout value, try increasing your current value:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
```

This might be closing your connection in server A before the entire request is sent to the server B.

Answer (score 5):

`max_input_vars` might also be hindering your curl post, if you're sending numerous parameters through. It has happened to me before - you can't change the setting on runtime, but only through `php.ini`.

Answer (score 4):

add `Expect:` to the header of curl

```
$headers = array( "Expect:" );
```

or

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Expect:"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. For a technical explanation as to why it works, at least in lmy case : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect#large_message_body.

Comment: Explanation about why it works : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expect#large_message_body.

Basically, you need this if the document's body you post is too large.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent so many hours exhausting resources on the internet before I came across your post that finally solved my problem.