# What is the size or length limit of curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have use following line to send files.

```
$curl_cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k -d \"$post_data\" $url 2>/dev/null";
```

**full Code:**

```
$rec_name  = $_POST['rec_name'];
$fax_no    = $_POST['fax_no'];
$filename  = $_FILES['attach']['name'];
$filedata  = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['attach']['tmp_name']));
$post_data = "faxno=$fax_no&recipname=$rec_name&faxfilenames[0]=$filename&faxfiledata[0]=$filedata";

$curl_cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k -d \"$post_data\" $url 2>/dev/null";
```

so the length of `$post_data` is too big, beacause it is dependent of file data. if file is large the data is also too large.

so my quetion is what is the maximim limit of data send using this method?

Comment: check this SO answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344528/curlopt-postfields-has-a-length-or-size-limit

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091151/i-am-trying-to-make-a-post-request-to-a-url-using-curl-but-getting-this-error

Answer (score 1):

curl has no limit for this, but your shell has a limit for how long command lines you can use.

That limit depends on many factors so I can't tell you a specific value.

Comment: This line  `$curl_cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k -d \"$post_data\" $url 2>/dev/null"` call from the browser.so it has a limitation?

Comment: command lines like that are ran with a shell, that shell has a limit